# Discover All Paths in Single Source, Multi-Terminal (possibly cyclic) Directed Graph

Tags: python, language-agnostic, graph-traversal

I have a graph `G = (V,E)`, where

- `V` is a subset of `{0, 1, 2, 3, …}`
- `E` is a subset of `VxV`
- There are no unconnected components in `G`
- The graph may contain cycles
- There is a known node `v` in `V`, which is the source; i.e. there is no `u` in `V` such that `(u,v)` is an edge
- There is at least one sink/terminal node `v` in `V`; i.e. there is no `u` in `V` such that `(v,u)` is an edge. The identities of the terminal nodes are not known - they must be discovered through traversal

What I need to do is to compute a set of paths `P` such that every possible path from the source node to any terminal node is in `P`. Now, if the graph contains cycles, it is possible that by this definition, `P becomes an infinite set. This is not what I need. Rather, what I need is for`P`to contain a path that doesn't explore the loop and at least one path that does explore the loop.

I say "at least one path that does explore the loop", as the loop may contain branches internally, in which case, all of those branches will need to be explored as well. Thus, if the loop contains two internal branches, each with a branching factor of 2, then I need a total of four paths in`P` that explore the loop.

For example, an algorithm run on the following graph:

```
         +-------+
         |       |
         v       |
1->2->3->4->5->6 |
         |  |  | |
         v  |  v |
         9  +->7-+
               |
               v
               8
```

which can be represented as:

```
1:{2}
2:{3}
3:{4}
4:{5,9}
5:{6,7}
6:{7}
7:{4,8}
8:{}
9:{}
```

Should produce the set of paths:

```
1,2,3,4,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,9
1,2,3,4,5,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,7,4,9
1,2,3,4,5,7,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,7,4,5,7,8
```

Thus far, I have the following algorithm (in python) that works in some simple cases:

```
def extractPaths(G, s=None, explored=None, path=None):
    _V,E = G
    if s is None: s = 0
    if explored is None: explored = set()
    if path is None: path = [s]
    explored.add(s)

    if not len(set(E[s]) - explored):
        print path
    for v in set(E[s]) - explored:
        if len(E[v]) > 1:
            path.append(v)
            for vv in set(E[v]) - explored:
                extractPaths(G, vv, explored-set(n for n in path if len(E[n])>1), path+[vv])
        else:
            extractPaths(G, v, explored, path+[v])
```

but it fails horribly in the more complex cases.

I'd appreciate any help as this is a tool to validate an algorithm that I have developed for my Master's thesis.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is totally unclear what does it mean to explore each loop once. Can you define it rigorously?

Comment: `4,5,7` is a loop, and thus a valid path may contain several repetitions of `4,5,6` (e.g. `1,2,3,4,5,7,4,5,7,4,5,7,4,5,7,4,5,7,8`). However, I am not interested in generating such a path. I am only interested in the path that (a) ignores this loop and (b) explores the loop once. Thus, I am interested in `1,2,3,4,5,7,8` and `1,2,3,4,5,7,4,5,7,8`. If there are branching nodes within a loop, I will need to generate paths that explore each of them as well. Does this make things clearer?

Comment: No, not really. I asked what does it mean to explore a loop once. An example does not make a rigorous definition. Let's try again. What makes two paths "essentially the same"? Is there a procedure one can run and say "we have done this path before"? Can you answer this in a general way, without invoking an example?

Answer (score 1):

I've though about this for a couple of hours, and have come up with this algorithm. It doesn't quite give the result you're asking for, but it's similar (and might be equivalent).

Observation: If we try to go to a node that has been seen before, the most recent visit, up until the current node, can be considered a loop. If we have seen that loop, we cannot go to that node.

```
def extractPaths(current_node,path,loops_seen):
    path.append(current_node)
    # if node has outgoing edges
    if nodes[current_node]!=None:
        for thatnode in nodes[current_node]:
            valid=True
            # if the node we are going to has been
            # visited before, we are completeing
            # a loop.
            if thatnode-1 in path:
                i=len(path)-1
                # find the last time we visited
                # that node
                while path[i]!=thatnode-1:
                    i-=1
                # the last time, to this time is
                # a single loop.
                new_loop=path[i:len(path)]
                # if we haven't seen this loop go to
                # the node and node we have seen this
                # loop. else don't go to the node.
                if new_loop in loops_seen:
                    valid=False
                else:
                    loops_seen.append(new_loop)
            if valid:
                extractPaths(thatnode-1,path,loops_seen)
    # this is the end of the path
    else:
        newpath=list()
        # increment all the values for printing
        for i in path:
            newpath.append(i+1)
        found_paths.append(newpath)
    # backtrack
    path.pop()

# graph defined by lists of outgoing edges
nodes=[[2],[3],[4],[5,9],[6,7],[7],[4,8],None,None]

found_paths=list()
extractPaths(0,list(),list())
for i in found_paths:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This won't work. When this generates `1,2,3,4,9`, it will mark `4` as having been seen. Thus, it will not generate a path containing the edge `(7,4)`, generating an incomplete `P` at best

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now. Maybe you can allow each node to be seen twice or something?

Comment: But without knowing the branching factor of every following node (and whether that node is a looping node, itself), it's impossible to determine how many times each node should be allowed to be seen. Since I don't have this information beforehand, such a modified DFS/BFS won't work

Comment: This is more difficult than I thought. If the last 0 to N nodes seen are the same as the last N+1 to 2*N nodes seen, the next node cannot be the 2*Nth node, because that would mean beginning a possible third iteration of a loop. Would I be correct in stating this?

Comment: Possibly correct. What if there were two branches within a loop, each of which contains an internal loop and eventually connects back to the top of the outer loop? Then, such a `c*N` analysis won't work, without further analyzing the innards of every node or predetermining `c`. Also, let's not forget that it is possible for a node within an internal loop to have two branches: one out of the loop, and one back into the loop

Comment: I've completely overhauled my answer. What I've got doesn't quite give the result you requested, but I think it's equivalent.